# some recipients missing email on form submission

Tags: exm

In `Sitecore 9.1.0` we have an automated `email campaign` where 4 recipients are supposed to receive an email on form submission but on submission-only 2 of them are receiving the email and the rest 2 are skipped according to the `EXM` logs with below message -

`The sender’s email is invalid`.

This might prevent successful dispatch
But these senders are getting emails on QA for the same campaign and on prod with the different campaigns and all the `SMTP` and configs same for QA and prod.

Comment: did you check if there is any sending limit defined in EXM:https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/exm/101/email-experience-manager/define-sending-limits-in-the-content-editor.html

Comment: there is no limit defined as such